# Hue Creating a New Hue Application

Tags: hue

I try to creat a new Hue application according to http://cloudera.github.io/hue/docs-2.5.0/sdk/sdk.html#fast-guide-to-creating-a-new-hue-application. However, when I run the command 'make apps'. It returns the result which is a little strange.In Not synced, there is only desktop, but it should have useradmin, hbase and so on. Because of this, when I run 'build/env/bin/hue runserver_plus ip:port', there will be an error saying 'importerror no module named useradmin'. I don't know how to solve the problem.
Any tips are appreciate!

Comment: Have you installed all the pre-requisites https://github.com/cloudera/hue#development-prerequisites ? What are you typing on the CLI?

Comment: Hue comes with the CDH 5.2 parcel and is added as a service from cloudera manager. In fact, I can see the normal apps in http://ip:8888. However, when I create a new app, and run the command 'build/env/bin/hue runserver_plus ip:port' in hue installation directory. I can't open http://ip:port and it returns an error saying importerror no module named useradmin.

Answer (score 1):

I have find the solution. http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Web-UI-Hue-Beeswax/HUE-3-5-0-SDK-Errors/td-p/12066 and http://grokbase.com/p/cloudera/hue-user/137rh65vkc/hue-users-creation may be helpful.